# android - Jar mismatch - android-support-v4.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-appcompat

I have been using Eclipse for several years and devloped apps in Android now and then. No severe problem until now - I dont know what this comes from?
My old projects are ok but as soon as I launch a new android-application project I get the following errors

I know this question has been asked before but I can not find any solution

```
[2015-12-08 12:58:37 - test_android]    Length: 758727
[2015-12-08 12:58:37 - test_android]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2015-12-08 12:58:37 - test_android] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2015-12-08 12:58:39 - test2_dec08] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView,  unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing
[2015-12-08 12:58:45 - test_android] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_] Versions found are:
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_] Path: C:\Users\john\workspace\testtest_\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_]   Length: 1364881
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_]   SHA-1: 91a1b1aabf740a6f64c2f73f5b0dc6611779ac8b
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_] Path: C:\Users\john\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_]   Length: 758727
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_]   SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2015-12-08 12:59:07 - testtest_] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing
[2015-12-08 12:59:10 - testtest_] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView,   unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing
```

I tried with one of the answer to this thread

[android-support-v4.jar dependency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609066/android-support-v4-jar-dependency-error)

that is to uppdate the support library for both the actual project AND the project appcompat_v7

But now older projects wont work either

greatful for help!!!

Comment: Did you try with this. I think you have to change the API level[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248579/error-in-declare-styleable-menuview-unable-to-find-attribute-androidpreserv)

Comment: @rasikag - that solved the problem!!!!!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, for C:\Users\john\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs your android support jar is old. Right Click on Project, click Android support tools->AddSuportLibrary. Error will be resolved.

or

Update SDK.

Answer (score 0):

When you import **appcompat_v7** project as library then **android-support-v4.jar** also included in **appcompat_v7**, so you have to remove **android-support-v4.jar** from your project/lib folder it already in **appcompat_v7** project, then clean your project and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

you have imported some project into your own created projected both have same library but different signature please use anyone copy from one and same replace with other